# How to create a key combination of Map from a list in Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of User object which I want to convert to a Map with key as FirstName+ Last Name and value as its ID. Is there any way to accomplish this using Streams ? . I tried the below but it didnt work since "Target type of the expression is not a functional interface". Should I use standard for loop to achieve this ? Any help is much appreciated.

```
List<User> users = userRepo.findAll();
Map<String,Long> userIdMap = users.stream()
                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getFirstName + "|" + User::getLastName, User::getId));
```

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toMap(u->u.getFirstName() + "|" + u.getLastName(), User::getId));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Type::method` is a *method reference*. In the case of `User::getFirstName`, this is already of the type `User -> String`.

Functions in Java are not *first class citizens*. There are no operators for composing them or concatenating them. The `+` operator for example is not defined for `User -> String (+) User -> String`. It *is* defined for `String + String`, though.

So what you want is not to write bare method references, but to create an expression that is overall of the type `User -> String`, but utilizes the `+` operator for actual strings.

A lambda accepting a `User` needs that as first parameter, and it needs to return a string. `u -> "Hello, World"` would be such a lambda. Putting it together as needed, you end up with:

`Function<User, String> userToFullName = u -> u.getFirstName() + "|"  + u.getLastName()`;

You can then use that function inside your collector:

```java
Function<User, String> userToFullName = user -> user.getFirstName() + "|"  + user.getLastName();
Map<String,Long> userIdMap = 
    users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(userToFullName, User::getId));
```

Or, if you do not want to store the lambda explicitly in a named variable:

```java
Map<String,Long> userIdMap = 
    users.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            user -> user.getFirstName() + "|"  + user.getLastName(), 
            User::getId
    ));
```

Comment: Nice answer! The only thing is I'd call the function something like `userToFullName` (to emphasise that it's a mapper), but it's rather a matter of taste...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko That certainly a valid point, I went here for duality with the already existing method names. On second thought, I like your suggestion better though and will change the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
User::getFirstName + "|" + User::getLastName
```

Here, concat the method reference is the wrong way to concat strings. You can use lambda expression this way

```
Map<String,Long> userIdMap = 
       users.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(u -> u.getFirstName() + "|" + u.getLastName(),
                                      User::getId));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Polygnome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64209743/1552534) gave an excellent answer to this.  But I look at it slightly differently.

Consider the following:

```
User u = new User();
Function<User, String> fnc1 = User::getFirstName;
```

Neither of these are allowed because they aren't Strings, they're method references. But you were trying to use the first one as a String and the following won't compile.

```
String name = User::getFirstName;
```

To get the name you would need to do the following where `u` is the reference to the desired class. And if all you had was a single method reference, this is how it would have been resolved.

```
name = fnc1.apply(u);
```

But that didn't lend itself to your string construct of string concatenation so you really needed to do
`u.getFirstName()` which the lambda `u->u.getFirstName()` permitted.

Just invoke the method with a lambda instead of a method reference.

```
List<User> users = userRepo.findAll();
       Map<String,Long> userIdMap = 
                  users.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(u->u.getFirstName() + "|" + u.getLastName(), 
                  User::getId));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its best if you do not append the firstName and LastName, instead use a different approach like -

```
Map<Pair<String, String>,Integer> employeePairs = employees.stream().collect(HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Integer>::new,
            (m, c) -> m.put(Pair.of(c.getFirstName(), c.getLastName()), c.employeeId),
            (m, u) -> {});
    employeePairs.get(Pair.of("firstname", "lastname")); // Access the map in this way
```

This saves a lot of String Concatenation in case of Large Data.

For this you need to add a maven Package that gives you the Pair functionality

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

And the import statement will be-

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
```

Comment: Slight difference, when there is a merge function specified with `toMap`  and what would have been assumed to be taken care of in its absence. But the output of your code would be different to that with two `User`s such as `"Ishan|","Ghosh"` and `"Ishan","|Ghosh"`.